# Compact-u16 - what is the purpose of this?

Tags: variables, blockchain

I was doing some research over the weekend on some blockchain dev in the Solana blockchain and came across a construct called Compact-u16.  The definition of this in the documentation says the following: "A compact-u16 is a multi-byte encoding of 16 bits. The first byte contains the lower 7 bits of the value in its lower 7 bits. If the value is above 0x7f, the high bit is set and the next 7 bits of the value are placed into the lower 7 bits of a second byte. If the value is above 0x3fff, the high bit is set and the remaining 2 bits of the value are placed into the lower 2 bits of a third byte.".

I have been coding for 30+ years.  Maybe I'm just old school on this, but why is there a construct to store 16 bits of data in 3 bytes?  This is just vastly inefficient from my standpoint.  Is there a reason for this?  On further research, I found a doc related to assembly instruction pointers, which referenced 7 instruction pointers that are useful for caching values when context switching in and out of the processor stack.  But this construct is used for a web app platform.  Like, literally, there is no reason that I have been able to find that justifies using 3 bytes to store 16 bits of data.  If the developers wanted to use an elegant bit mapping solution to compress space, why not just use a semaphore?  Why create a brand new construct that increases the storage requirements for the data by 33%.

What am I missing?

Comment: It increases the *maximum* storage to 3 bytes.  But the *minimum* is only 1 byte, and the *average* over values that are actually used in practice is hopefully less than 2.

Answer (score 6):

I had some similar confusion when reading the compact-u16 description. Based on the code for parsing them in the [solana python module](https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/master/src/solana/utils/shortvec_encoding.py) I believe they're doing something conceptually similar to UTF-8, and storing the number in 1-3 bytes depending on its size.

Basically instead of each byte having 8 bits of a number, it has 7 bits of the number and a flag (the most significant bit) that indicates whether the number continues in the next byte. For the largest numbers they need an extra byte, but for numbers less than 128 they need only one byte. Since Solana seems to use these for storing the length of arrays, if it's common that the length of the arrays is less than 128 then they will end up with fewer total bytes to transfer across all transactions.

Some examples I worked out for myself:

```
hex     |  compact-u16
--------+------------
0x0000  |  [0x00]
0x0001  |  [0x01]
0x007f  |  [0x7f]
0x0080  |  [0x80 0x01]
0x3fff  |  [0xff 0x7f]
0x4000  |  [0x80 0x80 0x01]
0xc000  |  [0x80 0x80 0x03]
0xffff  |  [0xff 0xff 0x03])
```

Comment: Does the pattern continues after third byte? The [doc](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/transactions#compact-u16-format) only describes to the third byte but I assume it supports infinite number of bytes?

Comment: @Hao-CherHong  "If the value is above 0x3fff, the high bit is set and the remaining 2 bits of the value are placed into the lower 2 bits of a third byte" The encoding is to support u16 numbers which means a fourth byte will never be required and only part of the third byte can ever be used.

Comment: fix url for solana python module: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/v0.23.3/src/solana/utils/shortvec_encoding.py